# How to create a parent theme for accesspress parallax theme?

Tags: child-theme, parent-theme

So, I'm currently using an AccessPress Parallax theme and I've created a child theme, however, it shows there is an error. It says "The parent theme is missing. Please install the "accesspressparallax" parent theme". What should I do about it? Is there something wrong with the theme?

The style.css file:

```
/*Theme Name: AccessPress Parallax
Theme URI: htt ps://accesspressthemes.com/wordpress-themes/accesspress-parallax/
Author: AccessPress Themes
Author URI: htt ps://accesspressthemes.com/
Description: AccessPress Parallax is a beautiful WordPress theme with Parallax design. Parallax design has become popular and is widely implemented these days. This is probably the most beautiful, feature rich and complete free WordPress parallax theme with features like: fully responsive, advance theme option panel, featured slider, advance post settings, services/team/blog/portfolio/testimonial layout, Google map integration, custom logo/fav icon, call to action, CSS animation, SEO friendly, translation ready, RTL support, custom CSS/JS and more! More over the theme is fully translation ready, WooCommerce Compatible, bbPress Compatible and fully support multilanguage via POLYLANG plugin. Demo: ht tp://accesspressthemes.com/theme-demos/?theme=accesspress-parallax Support forum: https://accesspressthemes.com/support/ Pro version: htt ps://accesspressthemes.com/wordpress-themes/accesspress-parallax-pro/ 
Version: 1.30
License: GNU General Public License v3 or later
License URI: ht tp://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
Text Domain: accesspress-parallax
Domain Path: /languages/
Tags: custom-background, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-menu, featured-images, one-column, right-sidebar, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready, two-columns, grid-layout, footer-widgets, blog, e-commerce, photography, portfolio

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.

AccessPress Parallax is based on Underscores http://underscores.me/, (C) 2012-2014 Automattic, Inc.*/
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to WPSE. Is this the `style.css` for your parent theme? Btw there are some errors in it, for example `https` is being written as `htt ps`.

Comment: Yes, I separated it because it didn't allow me to post more than two links. This is a style.css for my theme, yes.

Comment: please post your child theme style.css as well

Comment: Where do I find it?

Comment: the child theme style.css is the new one that you created. is the parent theme in the directory "accesspressparallax" ?

Comment: /*
Theme Name: AccessPress Parallax
Theme URI: https://accesspressthemes.com/wordpress-themes/accesspress-parallax/
Author: AccessPress Themes

Comment: Author URI: https://accesspressthemes.com/
Description: AccessPress Parallax is a beautiful WordPress theme with Parallax design. Parallax design has become popular and is widely implemented these days. This is probably the most beautiful, feature rich and complete free WordPress parallax theme with features like:

Comment: fully responsive, advance theme option panel, featured slider, advance post settings, services/team/blog/portfolio/testimonial layout, Google map integration, custom logo/fav icon, call to action, CSS animation, SEO friendly, translation ready, RTL support, custom CSS/JS and more!

Comment: More over the theme is fully translation ready, WooCommerce Compatible, bbPress Compatible and fully support multilanguage via POLYLANG plugin. Demo: http://accesspressthemes.com/theme-demos/?theme=accesspress-parallax Support forum: https://accesspressthemes.com/support/ Pro version: https://accesspressthemes.com/wordpress-themes/accesspress-parallax-pro/ 
Version: 1.30
License: GNU General Public License v3 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
Text Domain: accesspress-parallax
Domain Path: /languages/

Comment: Tags: custom-background, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-menu, featured-images, one-column, right-sidebar, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready, two-columns, grid-layout, footer-widgets, blog, e-commerce, photography, portfolio

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.

AccessPress Parallax is based on Underscores http://underscores.me/, (C) 2012-2014 Automattic, Inc.
*/

Comment: Sorry, had to separate it because it was too long. That is my child theme style.css. Actually, I think I don't quite understand what I'm doing. :( Should the baby theme be a different theme than the parent one?? Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong? :(

Comment: "Template is missing. Standalone themes need to have a index.php template file. Child themes need to have a Template header in the style.css stylesheet." Now this is what it shows...

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at this https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme/ .

Note that your child theme's CSS file has two required parameters. From the above link:

"The two necessary items in the code above are the lines starting with “Theme Name" and “Template.” The theme name tells WordPress what the name of your theme is, and this is displayed in the theme selector. The template tells WordPress which theme it should consider as the parent theme."

I notice also that your 'theme uri' value has an extra space in it.

The header of the `style.css` file should look similar to the example in the above link.